# How Can I Delete This Permalink in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIoL4.png)

Wordpress woocommerce. I didnt find brands permalink setting in my panel. Can you guys help me please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1hNG.png)

i need like this permalink type.

My site is wordpress and i use woocommerce plugin. I have this issues in my site please help me.

Comment: You can change the permalink structure by going to **woocommerce** > **settings** > **permalinks**. In the **"Custom structure"**, add the following:  `/%postname%/` which indicates that your structure should be www.website.com/post-or-product-name. See more in the wordpress documentation: [Customize permalinks](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/customize-permalinks/). Don't forget that changing permalink structure can impact your SEO.

Answer (score -1):

Add your 'one-plus' product to that 'product-brands' category.
Go to the Products -> Categories. You will be able to see 'Product Brand' category which you can see in my screenshot as a Accessories. If you have added your product in that particular category then the Count column will display the number of product are assigned in that category.

If you click 'View' which is next to Red coloured 'Delete'. It will redirect to your Product listing page of that Category. By clicking any product over there you will might get the your desired URL.

[image: Product Category Page]